# Change PySpark StringIndexer input_col param when wrapped in a Pipeline object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm building a `Pipeline` object to encode my category column using a `StringIndexer` object.

```
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol='FirstName',
                                  outputCol='FirstName_new',
                                  handleInvalid='keep',
                                  stringOrderType='frequencyDesc').fit(df)]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)

pipeline.write().overwrite().save(path)
```

I want to use the same pipeline object but on another column (I have a specific use-case which I need it). Is there any way I can change the `input_col` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setInputCol` method to set change the input column name.

```
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol='FirstName',
                                  outputCol='FirstName_new',
                                  handleInvalid='keep',
                                  stringOrderType='frequencyDesc')]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)

>>> print(pipeline.getStages()[0].getInputCol())
FirstName

pipeline.getStages()[0].setInputCol('test')

>>> print(pipeline.getStages()[0].getInputCol())
'test'
```

Note that you should not put `fit(df)` inside the pipeline - you should fit to the data using the pipeline, e.g. `pipeline.fit(df)`.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct usage for a single stage. But if you're using a pipeline, the usage is different.